# Laravel: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint - when migrating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, database-migration

I have table category which have parent of type of itself.

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Throws:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `categories` add constraint `categories_parent_id_foreign` foreign key (`parent_id`) references `categories` (`id`))
```

I've already tried making parent_id as foreign in seperate, Schema::table function yet with no success. Table is InnoDB type.

Comment: why are you creating a FK that references the same table that you're creating? parent_id should reference id on the parents table

Comment: As I mentioned in first line, categories have parents of categories

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didnt see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your FK from integer to bigInteger:

```
$table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
```

or

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable()->default(null);
```